# Opening a file from a new/different Projectile project in the same workspace in Doom Emacs

Tags: projectile, doom, persp-mode

If I'm working on one project and I switch over to a buffer from another the default behavior of Doom Emacs seems to be to open the new buffer in a new workspace (when workspaces are enabled). I want the default behavior to be to open it in the current workspace, but I don't want to disable workspace functionality in general. Is there a good way to do this?

After more research this seems to be an interaction between [persp-mode](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el) and projectile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a variable called +workspaces-on-switch-project-behavior. Its documentation states

```
Controls the behavior of workspaces when switching to a new project.

Can be one of the following:

t           Always create a new workspace for the project
'non-empty  Only create a new workspace if the current one already has buffers
            associated with it.
nil         Never create a new workspace on project switch.
```

Setting it to nil gives me the desired behavior, which is that a new workspace is not created when switching projects.